# is there a git index (staging area) visualisation tool

Tags: git

I'm mainly on Windows, though can use the git bash when required. I tend to visualise what's going on using `git gui` and `gitk` to see inter-relationships.

What I'm really looking for is a three way hierarchical visual comparison between my working directory, my staging area (index), and a (e.g. my_last) commit.

The comparison would most likely keep the three views synchronised and show how they differ: added / deleted / modified. Is there such a tool?

edit: kdiff3 [(see top of page 3)](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/KDiff3-Abstract.pdf) might be the tool, but how to set it up, where would it get Index from?

Comment: the awkwardness of git status is that you need the right mental model of what is where, and it doesn't do the extra comparison with your last commit from your current branch. There are many responses where  folk are told that git gave the right answer, and that they'd misunderstood what was happening. Its visualising that that I'm interested in. [I've avoided .gitignore issue here]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `git difftool` to help you integrate with kdiff3 and other GUIs.  You can use it 3-way for resolving merge conflicts using `git mergetool`, but I'm not sure a 3-way simultaneous comparison is useable in other contexts, because there isn't a common baseline that was diverged from.  Use `git difftool` to see what has changed between your index and working tree, and `git difftool --cached` to see the difference between what is staged and what is committed.

Comment: The tricky bit is a) passing trees rather than files, and b) finding how git would show those trees (particularly the index and the selected commit). The inability to visualise the Index (staging area) relative to the working directory and last commit is a common problem.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you were talking about tree level visualization.  Do you mean something like git-cola's cola-classic, which has a tree that marks modified, partially staged, or staged for each file?

Comment: I wasn't aware of git cola, so I'll have a look at that.

Answer (score -2):

There is a quite good git GUI tool for Windows: [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/)

It includes "Tortoise merge" which is a diff tool. I assume you can see the changes between files/branches/commits/... there.

Comment: Ok, I didn't really realise hat this was the point in the question.